# Pandas str.contains over a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I use something like the following to update my dataframe

```
df.loc[(df['Message'].str.contains('hello', case=False)),'SomeSeries'] = 'SomeUpdate'
```

But I might want to update when my series contains `'hello'` or `'bicycle'` or `'monday'`, etc. 
Obviously, I could iterate over a list but I'm wondering if there is a way to do that in a single line? I would like something like

```
watchlist = ['hello','bicycle','monday']
df.loc[(df['Message'].str.contains(watchlist, case=False)),'SomeSeries'] = 'SomeUpdate'
```

Comment: instead of df['Message'].str.contains you can do df['Message'].isin, however, without sample data I can't give you a result

Answer (score 5):

you need,

```
 df.loc[(df['Message'].str.contains('|'.join(watchlist), case=False)),'SomeSeries'] = 'SomeUpdate'
```

Comment: Might want to make that `'|'.join(re.escape(w) for w in watchlist)` just in case the watchlist contains regex special characters and should be treated as literals.

Comment: Added `regex=False`

Comment: That won't work then... it'll only find things that happen to contain the list of pipe delimited watch words...